# ¿Cómo manipular un campo padre con jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Deseo que al dar click sobre la imagen en la clase lave-linge, pueda aunmentar 1 en mi campo rooms. El código es el siguiente

```
<div class="row">
<div class="choice-item">
<span class="img lave-linge"></span>
<span class="label">Lave-linge</span>
<input type="text" data-m3="1.00" placeholder="0" name="rooms">
</div>

<div class="choice-item">
<span class="img carton"></span>
<span class="label">Carton</span>
<input type="hidden" value="0.04" name="rooms[salle-de-bain][carton][m3]">
<input type="hidden" value="Carton" name="rooms[salle-de-bain][carton][name]">
<input type="text" data-m3="0.04" placeholder="0" name="rooms[salle-de-bain][carton][value]">
</div>
</div>
```

Estoy intentando con esto tratando de obtener el index, pero no funciona:

```
$( ".choice-item .img" ).click(function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();

  var el = $(this).index();
  console.log(el)
    
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Para tu código específico lo que necesitas creo que es esto:

```
$(".choice-item .img").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  input = $(this).parent().find("input[type='text']")[0]
  if (input.value == "") {
    input.value = "1"
  } else {
    input.value = parseInt(input.value) + 1
  }
});
```

Snippet de ejemplo:

```js
$(".choice-item .img").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  input = $(this).parent().find("input[type='text']")[0]
  if (input.value == "") {
    input.value = "1"
  } else {
    input.value = parseInt(input.value) + 1
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="choice-item">
    <span class="img lave-linge"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/35/Plus_sign.jpg" width="40px"></span>
    <span class="label">Lave-linge</span>
    <input type="text" data-m3="1.00" placeholder="0" name="rooms">
  </div>

  <div class="choice-item">
    <span class="img carton"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/35/Plus_sign.jpg" width="40px"></span>
    <span class="label">Carton</span>
    <input type="hidden" value="0.04" name="rooms[salle-de-bain][carton][m3]">
    <input type="hidden" value="Carton" name="rooms[salle-de-bain][carton][name]">
    <input type="text" data-m3="0.04" placeholder="0" name="rooms[salle-de-bain][carton][value]">
  </div>
</div>
```

Aún así, se podria optimizar mejor si usaras campos input con tipo **number** en lugar de **text**, pues obligas a realizar el **parseInt** para realizar los incrementos en javascript, y usaras **value** por defecto válidos en lugar de **placeholder**.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que no esta my clara la pregunta, y i te entendí, al hacer click en una imagen deseas que se incremente el valor de un input, pero tu input no tiene Clase o un id

Va un ejemplo, espero te ayude

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <h3>Prueba de incremento de valor</h3>
    <img id="lave-linge" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" with="" alt="">
    <form action="">
      <br>
      <label for="rooms">Clicks en la imagen: </label>
      <input type="text" name="input1" id="rooms" style="width: 50px;">
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var clickimagen = document.getElementById("lave-linge");
      var rooms = document.getElementById("rooms");
      var contador = 0;
      clickimagen.onclick = function() {
        contador++;
        rooms.value = contador;
      }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```